# C++ Get length of const char* [ ] in vector

Tags: c++, vector, const-char

How do I get the length of const char* arrays indexes?

The vector:

```
std::vector<const char*> _infoBarText;
```

The const char* []:

```
const char* text[4] = {"Current T:", "Target T:", "Time elapsed:", "Time remaining:"};
```

Assigning the char array to the vector:

```
_infoBarText.assign(text, text+4);
```

How can I get the length of the individual strings, like `"current T"`, from the vector?

Comment: Same way you get the length of any C-style string. But why are you using C-style strings to begin with?

Comment: That information is lost when you use `const char*` to refer to string literals. You will have to counts then characters again, usually with `std::strlen`.

Comment: I'd suggest using a `std::vector<std::string_view>` instead.  Then you just need `vector_name[index].size()`

Answer (score 7):

Raw `C` strings (bare `char*`-s) are not a perfect fit for modern `C++` code.

If you change it to `std::vector<std::string_view>` you get your problem solved without (virtually) any overhead (given you are initializing it with literals) and as a bonus you will potentially make it safer and more usable.

See the [cppreference article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string_view) for details.

Example ([GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/myzc4a)):

```
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace std::literals;

    std::vector<std::string_view> strs = { "hello"sv, "there"sv };

    for (auto&& str: strs)
        std::cout << str << str.size();

    return 0;
}
```

GodBolt [Code Insight](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPHN0cmluZ192aWV3PgojaW5jbHVkZSA8dmVjdG9yPgojaW5jbHVkZSA8aW9zdHJlYW0+CgppbnQgbWFpbigpIHsKICAgIHVzaW5nIG5hbWVzcGFjZSBzdGQ6OmxpdGVyYWxzOwoKICAgIHN0ZDo6dmVjdG9yPHN0ZDo6c3RyaW5nX3ZpZXc+IHN0cnMgPSB7ICJoZWxsbyJzdiwgInRoZXJlInN2IH07CgogICAgZm9yIChhdXRvJiYgc3RyOiBzdHJzKQogICAgICAgIHN0ZDo6Y291dCA8PCBzdHIgPDwgc3RyLnNpemUoKTsKCiAgICByZXR1cm4gMDsKfQ==&rev=1.0) Output (note the `std::operator""sv("hello", 5ul)`):

```
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  using namespace std::literals;
  std::vector<std::string_view> strs = std::vector<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > > >{std::initializer_list<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >{std::operator""sv("hello", 5ul), std::operator""sv("there", 5ul)}, std::allocator<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > >()};
  {
    std::vector<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > > > & __range = strs;
    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > *, std::vector<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > > > > __begin = __range.begin();
    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > *, std::vector<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > > > > __end = __range.end();

    for( ; __gnu_cxx::operator!=(__begin, __end); __begin.operator++() )
    {
      std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> > & str = __begin.operator*();
      std::operator<<(std::cout, std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >(str)).operator<<(str.size());
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do note that there will be an `O(N)` traversal of each of the c-strings to get their size when building the vector.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - thanks, corrected the answer

Comment: @NathanOliver - no, not with literals.

Comment: Can you point out how it would get the size otherwise?  All it has is a pointer and the constructor says it calls `Traits::length(s)` which requires a traversal.

Comment: @NathanOliver - added an example, please take a look

Answer (score 2):

The long way:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstring> // for strlen

std::vector<const char*> _infoBarText;
char const *str = _infoBarText[0]; // or any other valid index
auto len = std::strlen(str);
```

Short:

```
auto len = std::strlen(_infoBarText[0]);
```

Comment: Why even introduce `str`?  `auto len = strlen(_infoBarText[0]);` does the same thing

Comment: @NathanOliver Of course, but that way it's easier to bridge the mental gap between indexing the vector and passing the const* char to strlen.